# How to get each percentages of parameters's contribution in R h2o deeplearning package?

Tags: r, parameters, deep-learning, h2o

How to get each percentages of parameters's contribution in R h2o deeplearning package?

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init(ip = "localhost", port = 54321, startH 2O = TRUE)
irisPath = system.file("extdata", "iris.csv", package = "h2o")
iris.hex = h2o.importFile(localH2O, path = irisPath)
h2o.deeplearning(x = 1:4, y = 5, data = iris.hex, activation = "Tanh")
h2o.shutdown(localH2O)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are building your model, add the following condition: `variable_importance = T`

This will ensure that when your model is built, it will return your variable importances.

In the Deep Learning demo for R, this requires that you modify the model building process. First, launch the demo by running the following code:

```
library(h2o)
conn <- h2o.init(nthreads = -1)
demo(h2o.deeplearning)
```

Then, adjust the code the initiates your model build by adding in the condition mentioned earlier:

```
model = h2o.deeplearning(x = setdiff(colnames(prostate.hex), c("ID","CAPSULE")), y = "CAPSULE", training_frame = prostate.hex, activation = "Tanh", hidden = c(10, 10, 10), epochs = 10000, variable_importances = T)
```

Finally, you can do the following to get your variable importances:

```
> h2o.varimp(model)
Variable Importances:
  variable relative_importance scaled_importance percentage
1      PSA            1.000000          1.000000   0.175660
2      VOL            0.937293          0.937293   0.164645
3  GLEASON            0.930565          0.930565   0.163463
4      AGE            0.799607          0.799607   0.140459
5    DCAPS            0.793741          0.793741   0.139429
6    DPROS            0.703781          0.703781   0.123626
7     RACE            0.527824          0.527824   0.092718
```

Hope this helps!